# Fetching google's answers, and displaying them?

Tags: python, urllib2, google-search

I'm starting a personal assistant project. I've noticed that if you type something like "How old is Obama" on Google, the first hit is a little thing that says "51 years (August 4, 1961)". This works for a lot of things, like, if you type "Who is Romney's wife" it returns "Ann Romney (m. 1969)". This is incredibly useful. How can I fetch this data and retrieve it?

Also, if nothing pops up, like saying "How much money is google worth", then scan each of the hits one by one and determines it. (I can do the determination part, I just need to know the scanning).

Can this be done using `urllib2`?

Comment: Before you go ahead with a solution, I would suggest to take a look into the [Google Terms of Service](http://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/terms/)

Comment: If you find that Google cannot solve your needs, take a look at DuckDuckGo and in particular DuckDuckHack. It is designed, among other things, with this in mind.

Comment: You cannot send automated queries according to Google terms of service. So I do not see any possible solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) ?

Its more helpful in doing dynamic computations based on a vast collection of built-in data, algorithms, and methods.

Also, Here is an example:
[How old is Obama](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=How%20old%20is%20Obama)